# Team City nightly build fails to start

Tags: teamcity-7.0

I have a Team City instance running on my PC.

I've set up a nightly build to run at midnight each night, even if there are no checkins to build.

I leave the PC locked at night so assume the build should trigger.

However I keep getting "Unable to collect changes", "Failed to start build", "Failed to collect changes, error: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210003: Unknown host MySVNServer".

If I set the build to run during the day, it triggers fine, even when the PC is locked.

I have a checkin triggered build, and a couple of others for 1 off ad-hoc builds to the same environment, they all run fine.

Will Team City build fail if I am not "logged in", is the fact the PC is locked causing the issue?

Comment: Wondering if you ever figured this out conclusively. I'm having the same issue but with Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too got this error message once. As far as I have been able to see, it was due to the server hosting our SVN repository crashing and restarting. The TeamCity project looking at this repository remained in a faulted state for some reason. Running the build manually once fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it shouldn't have anything to do with the system being locked during the midnight.

I can see by your errors, TeamCity is not able to collect changes from SVN (even you've set it to run when there are no pending changes, the runner will ping SVN for any if existing during the time build is triggered)

Check if the VCS settings are right and you are pointing to the right URL.